# Return the index number of span element on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have many span tags, when i hover on 3RD span tag it should return its position i.e. "3"

```
<div class="main">
    <span class="spanClass"></span>
    <span class="spanClass"></span>
    <span class="spanClass"></span>
    <span class="spanClass"></span>
    <span class="spanClass"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your mean of return?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? StackOverflow is not for "make code for me". Read the "How to ask" guide on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple, you can use the jQuery function `index()`.

**like this:**

```js
$('.spanClass').mouseenter(function(){
  var index = $(this).index()+1; // +1 because the index starts at 0
  $('.content').html('Number: '+index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <span class="spanClass">First</span>
    <span class="spanClass">Second</span>
    <span class="spanClass">Third</span>
    <span class="spanClass">Fourth</span>
    <span class="spanClass">Fifth</span>
</div>
<p class="content"></p>
```

Comment: thnx for answer... but it will return all tags position like if is there any <h1> or <b> before span then it will start with 3rd.. what i need is i have count only <span> with the class "spanClass " in whole content

Answer (score 1):

Just with css:

```css
.main {
  counter-reset: num 0;
}

span {
counter-increment: num;
}

span:hover:after {
  content: 'number: 'counter(num);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span class="spanClass">Span1 </span>
    <span class="spanClass">Span2 </span>
    <span class="spanClass">Span3 </span>
    <span class="spanClass">Span4 </span>
    <span class="spanClass">Span5 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even consider that! Nice one!

Comment: @SarfarajKazi , i think ,answer is yes but ask it in other question.